# Local System DateFormat in javaScript

Tags: date-format, sapui5

I have searched the forum. I got very close answers and I am able to partly solve the problem I am facing, but need a little more clarity whether this is possible or any available option is there. The problem is like below.

I am using SAP UI5.
I have DatePicker in one screen and there the date pattern is shown using the code below:

```
this._enddatepicker = new mii.control.miiDatePicker({ value: { path: "/dateValue", type: new sap.ui.model.type.Date({ pattern: "MM-dd-yyyy" })} });
```

So now it shows 08-29-2000

But I want to show the dates As per Local PC/System Date; So if Date is shown in toolbar as 2000-08-29, in the screen it needs to show in the same format. For that I have used the below code:

```
this._enddatepicker = new mii.control.miiDatePicker({ value: { path: "/dateValue", type: new sap.ui.model.type.Date({ setLocal:oLocale })} });
```

But here is the problem: it is taking the `LongDate` format. So if the long date format is `dd-MMMM-yyyy` it shows 29,August 2000. but the `Date` in the toolbar is in short date format `dd-MM-yyyy`, which I need to display on the screen.

Are there any options or ways to show the same?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
this._enddatepicker = new mii.control.miiDatePicker({
    value: {
        path: "/dateValue",
        type: new sap.ui.model.type.Date({
            setLocal: oLocale
        }),
        // you can specify style as long/short/medium/full
        formatOptions: {
            style: 'medium'
        }
    }
});
```